# Compare 2 columns with csv values in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, csv, sql-server-2012

How to compare these 2 columns in SQL Server 2012 which store csv values? I want to return values that are common.

```
column1 - 2,3,4,5
column2 - 4,5,6
```

The query should return 4,5 or at least a boolean whether they have values in common.

I tried using xquery but couldn't make it work

Comment: are you saying that column stores those values in a comma separated list? This goes against normalization and the design of SQL Server. You are going to need a splitter function for this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is clear. You need to split the values and then to use a technique to match the same ones.

In order to split values, I am using casting the them to XML and then using `nodes()`. This is old technique which works for all SQL Server editions. Anyway, I would advice (if not able to upgrade to SQL Server 2016 + and use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) to check and try to implement [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) SQL CLR functions pack - it will make the coding easier and clearer.

```
DECLARE @column1 VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@column2 VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @column1 = '2,3,4,5'
      ,@column2 = '4,5,6';


WITH CTE([column1], [column2])
AS
(
    -- this can be replaced with your actual query selecting data from the table
    SELECT  CAST(N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@column1, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>' AS XML)
           ,CAST(N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@column2, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>' AS XML)

)
SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)'))) AS Code 
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY [column1].nodes('//r') Tbl(Col)
INTERSECT 
SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)'))) AS Code 
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY [column2].nodes('//r') Tbl(Col);
```

[image]

I am using `INTERSECT` but you can use `INNER JOIN`, too.